# TypeScript : sourceMap includes node_modules despite exclusion settings

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm converting a legacy node.js/express application to TypeScript. I set `tsconfig.json` to exclude `node_modules`, however when I compile, there's still source map generated for this directory.

When starting the app, the following error occurs:

`Error: Cannot find module './src/middleware-wrapper'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)`

Removing the `node_modules` directory that is generated in the `/dist` folder solves this.

How can I prevent node_modules being generated in `/dist` or is there something else being done wrong?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude" : [
    "node_modules/**/*", "coverage/**/*", "test/**/*", "copyStaticAssets.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: In the exclude section, try changing your current exclusion with `"./node_modules/*"`

Comment: It still outputs node_modules - seems that turning on allowJS causes it to ignore exclusions. Makes it difficult to set up mixed language code-base without hacks.

Comment: Yes, TypeScript do compile files, that imported from your sources, despite ignore rules. I have also [stuck with this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12725) when worked on angular aot build.